# postgresql: How to use variables(some column value of a row) in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns `id`,`time`,`value`

STEP1: get the time value from the recent row

i.e `SELECT time FROM tablename ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1`

STEP2: get all the rows who are within last 5 minutes from this time.

How can i do this

Comment: Is the time on the most recent row the latest time?

Comment: Yes, the time is the recent on the latest row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.time > (SELECT t2.time - INTERVAL '5 minute'
                FROM tablename t2
                ORDER BY id desc
                LIMIT 1
               );
```

If this is really not the most recent time and you want anything within five minutes, then moving the calculation to the `FROM` clause is simpler:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT t2.time - INTERVAL '5 minute'
      FROM tablename t2
      ORDER BY id desc
      LIMIT 1
     ) last_row
WHERE t.time > last_row.time - INTERVAL '5 minute' AND
      t.time <= last_row.time;
```

If you want the most recent time and anything within five minutes of that, you can use window functions as well:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MAX(t.time) OVER () as max_time
      FROM t
     ) t
WHERE t.time > max_time - INTERVAL '5 minute';
```

Comment: Is `SELECT t2.time - INTERVAL '5 minute' FROM devicedata t2 ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1` same as `(SELECT t2.time FROM tablename t2 ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1) - INTERVAL '5 minute'` . I am new the syntax

Comment: @Santhosh . . . Yes, those are equivalent.  It is just whether the five minutes are subtracted before or after the the row is fetched.